# jqueryui sortable issue with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, cross-browser, jquery-ui-sortable

I created a horizontally scrollable container with sorting.

There are some requirements:

- The bounding box is fixed width
- Must scroll when overflowing, no wrapping

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vXG2/ (drag columns with pink header)

This works perfectly with: IE9, Opera, Safari

But not working with: Chrome, Firefox

In both Chrome and Firefox, the elements start jumping around. (Incidentally, the behavior on Firefox is different between Windows and OSX, using exactly the same version - 17.0.1)

When initially designing it using `float:left`, all browsers behaved correctly, but due to no wrapping requirement, I cannot use this.

Any ideas how to fix this? Or is this a jqueryui bug/issue?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

If I add `border-collapse: collapse` it behaves correctly again in Chrome, but breaks in Opera.

**EDIT 2:**

Found a 'weak' workaround going back to `float:left`: See http://jsfiddle.net/6vXG2/1/. Not ideal, but OK for now. Still open for suggestions.